# Slab Calculation in SQL

Tags: sql-server

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE
(
     SlabFrom INT
    ,SlabTo INT
    ,Amount DECIMAL(18,3)
)

INSERT INTO @TABLE (SlabFrom, SlabTo, Amount)

SELECT 0, 300000, 0.788
UNION ALL
SELECT 300001, 700000, 0.735
UNION ALL
SELECT 700001, 1300000, 0.683
UNION ALL 
SELECT 1300001, 9999999, 0.630

SELECT * FROM @TABLE

DECLARE @QUANTITY INT = 300001
```

I am very new to sql and want to write a while loop in which I can first check if the quantity is less than SlabTo value if yes then I want to insert the record in certain temp table which I am able to do. But suppose if the quantity is exceeding slabTo value then whatever quantity is then I want to insert only that quantity which will be equal to SlabTo - SlabFrom value in particular slab and remaining in the next slab. This i want to do in a while loop only

Eg. If Quantity is 300001 Then as in First slab we will check SlabTo - SlabFrom i.e 300000 - 0 = 300000 so rate applied will be 0.788 for 300000 quantity and 
now remaining 1 will go in next slab for which rate applied will be 0.735

Can anybody assist on this query.

Comment: Since you say you are new to sql I want to help you. Stop thinking about data as rows. You do NOT want to use a loop. You instead need to think about data in sets. Looping is horrible for performance. The easiest way to do this is think about what column(s) you can use, not about the row. The biggest issue here though is that it is not at all clear what you want to do. What is the expected output?

Answer (score 1):

Here's my stab at it:

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE
(
     SlabFrom INT
    ,SlabTo INT
    ,Amount DECIMAL(18,3)
)

INSERT INTO @TABLE (SlabFrom, SlabTo, Amount)

SELECT 0, 300000, 0.788
UNION ALL
SELECT 300001, 700000, 0.735
UNION ALL
SELECT 700001, 1300000, 0.683
UNION ALL 
SELECT 1300001, 9999999, 0.630

SELECT * FROM @TABLE

DECLARE @QUANTITY INT = 300001

;with AmountsPerSection as
(
    select t.*
        , (select min(x) from (values (@Quantity - coalesce(nullif(t.SlabFrom, 0) - 1, 0)), (t.SlabTo)) y(x)) as AppliedAmount
    from @TABLE t
), cleansedAmountsPerSection as
(
    select SlabFrom
        , SlabTo
        , Amount
        , case when AppliedAmount < 0 then 0 else AppliedAmount end as AppliedAmount
    from AmountsPerSection
)
select *
    , AppliedAmount * Amount as Value
from cleansedAmountsPerSection
```

The first CTE figures out how much of the amount goes into each of the buckets.  The second removes any negative values.  The last select does the calculations.

Comment: From the above query, I got the desired result which was like First 300000 quantity was charged Rs. 0.788 and remaining 1 was charged Rs 0.735. Now there is one confusion if again the quantity received is 200,000 then I want to check if there is any balance in the first slab in current scenario there isn't as we have already utilized that slab when we calculated the rate for 300,000 quantity, so I want to move to next slab and check the balance in 2nd slab and apply the rate to that quantity. This is what I keep on doing every time on the quantity.